# How do I import a custom.. package ( ? ) into netbeans 6.8

Tags: java, netbeans, import

First time java user, just installed netbeans 6.8 on Ubuntu 10.04

I'm trying to use this plugin:
https://bitbucket.org/wwmm/oscar4/wiki/Home

to run the test code here:
https://bitbucket.org/wwmm/oscar4/wiki/Examples

code thus far:
http://pastie.org/3364457

SO how do I configure netbeans to be able to use this Oscar-4 package?

Answer (score 3):

Going off of Jayan answer:

1. Download the relevant .jar files
2. Create new netbeans project
3. In top-left panel right click "Libraries" >> "Properties"
4. Add Jar/Folder
5. Locate the .jar file from step #1 >> click "Ok" ( to exit out of dialogue box )
6. Left click on the "light bulb exclamation" seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PDE7.png
7. Select "Add Import for ***_*_** "

And you're golden!

Answer (score 0):

Roughly :

1. download the relevant jars
2. create library and
3. [add library to     project.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath)

Once this is done, the editor will automatically ask to fix the import when it sees classes that matches in your library.